# How can i fix my null pointer exception

Tags: android

I've been trying to fix this null pointer exception but I cant. I know its pointing to a null object but I don't how to fix it. I am beginner in Java programming so please don't get mad if this is a stupid question.

Here is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //EditText
        final EditText etTask = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        final String Task = etTask.getText().toString();

        //Button
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        //Null Fix

        //OnClickListeners
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                itemsAdapter.add(Task);
                etTask.setText("");

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Here is my Logcat:

```
09-04 06:58:32.704  16735-16735/com.example.elias.doit E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.elias.doit, PID: 16735
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ArrayAdapter.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.elias.doit.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:38)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
09-04 06:58:40.564  16735-16735/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 16735 SIG: 9
```

Comment: remove `itemsAdapter.add(Task);`

Comment: what is `Task` here `itemsAdapter.add(Task);`

Comment: Initilaize your  itemsAdapter adapter by 
itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Did the edit help Dale?

Answer (score 2):

Your `itemsAdapter` is never initialized. And it has no values at all. That's why you're getting a [`NullPointerException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) when you call your `add()`.

Try to do this:

```
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();

// add some data to your ArrayList.

itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
```

You can also use a `String[]` array instead of an `ArrayList<String>` or any other `List<String>` for that matter.

---

On your code it should look like:

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> data;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //EditText
    final EditText etTask = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final String task = etTask.getText().toString();

    data = new ArrayList<>();

    itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);

    //Button
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);



    //OnClickListeners
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            data.add(task);
            itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            etTask.setText("");

        }
    });
```

---

**Edit:** If you're creating that `ArrayAdapter` to use in something like a `ListView`. Where is it on your code? I guess you also forgot to get it.

Something like:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.yourListView);
// initialize the adapter and stuff.
lv.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
```

For further reading on `ListView` and adapters, take a look at [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html), and [this tutorial](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView). Also, check [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html).

Comment: It isn't an `ArrayList`

Comment: My bad. Thought of creating a list to use in the adapter hehe.

Comment: why remove that line? @Mauker

Comment: You don't have to, I've mistaken it for something else. Take a look at the edit @Dale

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your adapter `itemsAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(...);`

Comment: It depend on your requirement . there are multiple implementation.

Comment: @Dale what is purpose of `ArrayAdapter` in your case?

Comment: For the use of list view and adding tasks. This is supposed to be a to do list app @Rustam

Comment: your question is unclear so try learning about `ArrayAdapter,ListView` http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your adapter in OnCreateView() and before adding any value,

```
itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, taskNames);
```

here taskNames can an array or arrayList of task names which you would have defined as,

```
    ArrayList<String> taskNames; // or String[] taskNames;
```

Let me know if it works for you...

And do mark it as answer so that it would be useful to others...

Answer (score 0):

You haven't created an instance of an `ArrayAdapter` for your `itemsAdapter` variable when you try to call the `add()` method on it.

Try to initialise it using:

```
itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
```

Note: `values` is either a `String[]` or `List<String>` so you'll need to pass that in  correctly

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this..!

```
ArrayList<MyClass> myList = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
   ArrayAdapter<MyClass> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyClass>(this, R.layout.row,
    to, myList.);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```